# Eclipse MPI parser error

Tags: eclipse, parsing, mpi

I have created a project using eclipse mpi support using PTP (Parallel Tools Platform). When i create any mpi program the parser (i.e the editor) shows errors in mpi code. The code compiles without any problems but it keeps on showing errors in mpi code. i think there is an error with the eclipse parser or some configuration that i am missing.

Can somebody guide me on this. While you are at it can you also explain me the reason for a debug/release folder in eclipse. i like to manage my makefiles on my own. Any problems in that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This screen (towards the end of the process of making a new mpi project with CDT/PTP) warns about the error you're describing, and says that you should go to the next screen to easily add the mpi header to your project.

[image: Pic of the box where it tells about the error]

I'm not sure what you mean by "explain the reasons for a debug/release folder."  If you just mean that you never use Eclipse's build command, that's fine, but Eclipse is built to have a lot of features; some people use all of them and some people barely use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

you need  setting include folder as this image [image]